# Como tornar uma tabela responsiva usando (Twitter) Bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby, layout-responsivo

Estou trabalhando numa aplicação web usando Ruby On Rails 4 e grande parte da interface consiste de tabelas.

Gostaria que sugerissem uma forma de detectar o tamanho da tela em uso e, com base nisso, ocultar certas colunas de cada tabela.

Comment: já que está utilizando Ruby, já pensou em utilizar o Zurb Foundation ao invés do Bootstrap?  Afinal o Zurb utiliza SASS e não LESS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Podes ocultar qualquer objecto por classe ou id usando o seguinte código:

```css
@media (max-width:768px) {
    #id_a_ocultar_em_tablet {
        display: none;
    }

    .classe_a_ocultar_em_tablet {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
    #id_a_ocultar_em_smartphone {
        display: none;
    }

    .classe_a_ocultar_em_smartphone {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Com as regras acima, podes criar CSSs especiais para cada dispositivo, caso queiras apenas esconder ou mostrar objectos podes usar estas classes, e fica tudo mais simples:

```css
.visible-phone
.visible-phone
.visible-tablet
.visible-desktop
.hidden-phone
.hidden-tablet
.hidden-desktop
```

Por exemplo:

```html
<div class="hidden-phone">Este texto nao aparece num smartphone</div>
<div class="visible-phone">Este texto SÓ aparece num smartphone</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Simplesmente use o componente `.table-responsive` que fornece o Bootstrap:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Pode encontrar mais informação na [documentação do projeto](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables).

Não é necessário *hackear* o CSS ou usar outros componentes diferentes da tabela como foi sugerido.

Answer (score 7):

Com o Twitter Bootstrap tudo fica mais fácil, basta você criar o HTML corretamente e incluir as classes certas em suas tags, visto que ele já tem todo o CSS criado para que você utilize o design responsivo.

Esse é um HTML básico de uma tabela responsiva:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

Aqui explica direitinho: [Bootstrap](http://alexanmtz.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

Comment: seria interessante colocar exemplos de código, não só citar uma fonte externa :)

Comment: Não coloquei pois achei bem simples, de qualquer forma... xD

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Deixe ver se percebi, devo incluir a classe respectiva dentro dos <th> e <td> que quiser ocultar? Por exemplo, <th class ="hidden-phone"></th><td class="hidden-phone"></td> - certo?

Comment: Não, com o bootstrap você não utiliza mais as tags table, td, th...
Existem classes do css criadas pelo bootstrap que servem para determinar que aquela "div" é uma tabela, outra pra "div" cabeçalho e assim por diante, a estrutura vai ser como se você estivesse montando uma tabela realmente, porem somente com divs, já essas classes, "hidden-phone" por exemplo, servem sim para determinar em quais mídias você quer que aquele conteúdo seja visualizado...eu não sei qual versão do bootstrap você está utilizando, mais lá no site deles tem tudo explicado em PT! http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: ja experimentei, e deu certo. Muito obrigado. Aceitei a pergunta de Toni porque é a que mais rapidamente ensina  como lidar com o problema. Se o meu criterio esta errado, por favor corrija-me.

Comment: Você que manda chefe...kkk

Comment: Só repare o seguinte, não duplique conteúdo em sua aplicação, aquele código já existe pronto no css do bootstrap, não o inclua novamente!

Comment: estive a ver o material de referencia para tabelas na pagina http://alexanmtz.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables e no exemplo usam <table> com <tr> e <td>

Comment: É possível das duas formas, porém acredito que seja muito mais prático usando apenas divs...ai vai de cada um...além de ser mais prático, o codigo da tabela fica com um visual muito mais agradável e de mais fácil manutenção...

Comment: @KennyRafael (acerca da duplicacao de conteudo): neste caso, se eu quiser apenas ocultar 1 ou 2 colunas duma tabela e manter-me em controle do que vai ser oculto e o que permanecera em vista, seria mais viavel adicionar a classe respectiva, nao? A proposito, obrigado pelas dicas, hei de dedicar mais tempo aos docs de Bootstrap.

Comment: Sim, com certeza, não sei qual é a complexidade do seu projeto, porém existem várias formas de fazer isso, você pode salvar as informações de quais colunas devem ter quais classes para ser ocultadas, e no momento de gerar essa tabela você imprime o valor salvo no banco de dados, ocultando da forma que quiser aquela coluna, essa é uma forma, se é a melhor ou não, vai depender muito de como está sendo feito seu projeto, existem outras formas também...

Answer (score 4):

Aqui tem uma opções interessantes pra tabelas responsivas:
http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

E não sei também qual versão do Bootstrap você está usando, mas a 3 tem umas alterações no modo de usar a grid...

Comment: Vinicius Diascanio muito bom, esses exemplos são realmente úteis!